# broke my code into fiddle not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i am planing to make my text box editable...
so i removed the id from the disabled code...
even i tested in fiddle its not working...
providing my cod below....
i am providing part of my code in fiddle i am not able to see the text box...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `input` instead of `form:input`, browser can render standard html tags and you have to provide standard html.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqqUY/1/)**

*Change*

```
<input id="behvrName" type="text" cssClass="icwText" path="" />
```

*To*

```
<input id="behvrName" type="text" cssClass="icwText" path="" />
```

cssClass and are also not standard attributes and you need to change them if you want them to be interpreted and act accordingly by browser. `cssClass` would be `class`.

Comment: `cssClass` and `path` are not standard HTML attributes. `cssClass` can probably be changed to `class`, but I have no idea what `path` is for.

Comment: if you really want to have custom attributes, it is a best practice to have a prefix "data-" on the attribute. For this case, it would be data-css-class.

Answer (score 0):

`spring:message` and `form:input` are not plain HTML tags; rather, they are pseudo-tags processed by your server-side framework. If you want to use JSFiddle, you must use plain HTML.

Furthermore, your `input`'s `id` is `behvrName`, but you're not selecting that. If you want to disable that `input`, use an appropriate selector `$('#behvrName')` in the JavaScript portion.